# Fast reporting with user parameters and temp result sets

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, mdx, dax

I have come across a problem with reporting from SQL Server databases using SSRS, that I wonder if you could help me with.

When you have a huge amount of data in a table, and you want to select only those rows within a certain criteria, and you want to allow the users to specify that criteria (for example, it might be a start date and end date), and you then want to take that data (within the criteria) and perform a ton of other transformations on it, including producing various temporary result sets along the way (using CTEs or Table Variables or Temp tables) to finally produce the report, this basically takes ages in SQL. You can do it, but your users might have to wait an hour or two from the moment they've hit View Report, to their report being rendered.

I don't know much about MDX or DAX, cubes or tabular models, but I wonder if there is a quicker way to do what I want. Note the important aspect of the problem: the user is specifying a criteria that has to go all the way back to the original table, and then various transformations (*including* temp result sets) have to be applied to produce the final report.

What is the best way to do this? Am I doing it the only way possible? I know it's a broad question, but I'd like to know, theoretically, what the answer is. Where should I be looking? Should I be looking at Cubes? Tabular Models? Should I be using R in SQL Server?

Comment: Define "a huge amount of data".  Is there proper indexing on the columns that you want the user to specify the criteria?

Comment: Sounds like a typically application of temporary tables.

Comment: for me sounds like a Datawarehouse scenario with data organized on Facts and Dimensions. Possible solutions using Microsoft Technology and SQL Server are SSIntegrationServices for the ETL Process and SSAnalysisServices for developing the cubes. By developing the cubes and the database architecture, the STAR-Schema will be needed in order to keep performance. Of course this is broad speaking so you can have a vision, you can start investigating this website for more infos... http://www.kimballgroup.com/

Comment: Yes it is indexed, data is about 300 million rows - we're not talking 'big' data by any means. But to take 100million rows into a temp table, then to perform a number of transformation on it, does take quite a while even with proper indexes. As for a star schema, my data is currently in one large flat table. I have no idea how having it in a slightly more normalised format (i.e. a star) is going to help.

Comment: By the way Gordon, I've got your book and it is *excellent*! Thank you very much for it.

Comment: Push the majority of work(processing) to ETL leaving only plain selects for the reporting dataset.

Answer (score 1):

There is always a balance when it comes to handling large datasets. Sometimes it makes sense to do some of the work ahead of time so that on-demand reports can run in a reasonable amount of time.

In order for a model to be a good option here are some general guidelines:

- Many reports would be able to use common attributes from the model
- The data involves aggregates, not just lists of records
- The data does **not** need to be live
- You have plenty of development and testing time
- Anyone who would be using it as a data source will have to have be
  trained on the structure and be at least slightly familiar with MDX

Another option for you to consider is to have a stored procedure that "prepares" the data for you overnight in a separate table. This table could be well indexed because the write time is not as important. They report would then point to this table to be able to quickly retrieve the data it needs to present. This shifts most of the preparation/aggregation work. You can still of course have parameters that limit how much of this data you pull back.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the little bit of information you've given us (300 million rows in a single non-normalized table), there is definitely a faster way.  However, there will not be any quick solutions and you haven't provided enough information for me to give any recommendations.

I think you may need to seek some professional help to review your infrastructure and needs along with your usage and objectives so you can be pointed in the right direction.